# How to resolve "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseOCR in java.library.path.."

Tags: java, eclipse, ocr

I am using AspriseOCR in my project for text recognition from the image. aspriseOCR.jar file is configured properly to my Eclipse Build Path Libraries, but getting the below error.  Could someone please guide me how to resolve this?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseOCR in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.loadLibrary(OCR.java:247)
at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.<init>(OCR.java:56)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved by copying below DLL files into "C:\Windows\System32" location, which can be found in "Asprise-OCR-Java.zip", downloaded from [asprise site](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/download.php?lang=java).

```
AspriseOCR.dll
DevIL.dll
ILU.dll
AspriseJTwain.dll
```

Comment: any solution for mac?

Comment: @comeback4you did you find a solution for mac?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `aspriseOCR.jar` from your build path, and move it to `libs` folder.