# How to configure AspriseOCR in Mac OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, ocr

I am trying to text recognition from the image with AspriseOCR. But I getting no AspriseOCR in java.library.path. I have configured JAR file in Eclipse properly but getting same error. I have found solution [How to resolve "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseOCR in java.library.path.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752705/how-to-resolve-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-aspriseocr-in-java-library-pa) but I have mac os x so this solution is not helpful to me. Anybody guide how to configure AspriseOCR in Mac OS X?

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=OCR_HOME :$LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add the OCR_HOME tothe library path
```

I have set this path and AspriseOCR opening and immediately close and showing below error.

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
String s = new OCR().recognizeCharacters((RenderedImage) image);



java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseOCR in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.loadLibrary(OCR.java:247)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.<init>(OCR.java:56)
    at com.smartsense.Slide_share.Register(Slide_share.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:98)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:79)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:77)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```